# How to integrate PJSIP with Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, pjsip, pjsua2

**Business requirement:**

Developing mobile app for making calls and sending messages using PJSIP for platforms Android, iOS and Windows using Xamarin.

**Steps taken:**

Android:

1. Build PJSIP for Android (.so file).
2. Created native lib (.AAR) for Android.
3. Created Xamarin.Android Java binading library by following steps mentioned in 
   https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/binding-a-java-library/binding-an-aar/
4. Created the respective folders (lib->arm64-v8a) for keeping .so file in .apk.

**Problem:**

Sample code snippet in Xamarin.Android:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);
            Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pjsua2");
            Account obj = new Account();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

Getting the following run time error on statement:

```
 (Java.Lang.JavaSystem.LoadLibrary("pjsua2"));:
```

Unhandled Exception:

```
Java.Lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "freeifaddrs" 
referenced by "/data/app/PJSIPForAndroid.Android-1/lib/arm64/libpjsua2.so"... occurred
```

This error is coming specifically on Mi and LeTv phones running android 6.0.1 and Samsung Tablet running android kitkat 4.4.

Comment: 1) how are you implementing `getifaddrs` (3rd-party source/lib?) 2) Your java code should be calling LoadLibrary 3) You can create a C# wrapper for  for the PJSIP library instead of bundling it inside a aar/Java library

Comment: Hi @SushiHangover, Please check the updated question and help